# LAN unplugged after waking up from standby mode

Tags: lan

I have a **Dell (Latitude D630C)** Laptop. The LAN connection shows unplugged after the system is waked up from standby mode. I have checked the system services related to LAN, are running fine and tried by restarting them but no solution.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using XP SP3